# CSS: 2 images layered on eachother, put links on both images

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

im trying to add the same link on both images, this is because I have a border box thing, and a home button within it, both are images and the home image is layered on top of the border.

Right now only the border has a link, so when I click on it, you have to avoid the home icon image because it'll not do anything, and press on the border.

I want to have both images to go to the same link. Here is the code:

```
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #select {
    background: url(../img/style/selection_bg.png) no-repeat bottom;
    width: 89px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #select:hover {
        background: url(../img/style/selection_bg_hover.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #home {
    background: url(../img/icons/home_icon.png) no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 26px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 27px;
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0px;
}

<div id="pageTop"> <a href="http://www.google.com/" title="base" id="logo"></a>
  <div id="pageTopWrap"> <a href="http://www.google.com/" title="Go to home" id="select"></a>
    <div id="home">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 2 link are going to the same place why not wrap everything with 1 link

```
<div id="pageTop">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" title="base" id="logo">
        <div id="pageTopWrap">
            <div id="home"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```